# Run custom service remotily on Linux

Tags: linux, services

**On the server side :** ( @ip for example 10.0.0.3 )

Consider this simple script named `script.sh` : ( `/home/user/script.sh` )

```
#!/bin/bash
echo good
```

Let's create new service named `script.sh` under xinetd to run script above : ( `/etc/xinetd.d/script.sh` )

```
service script.sh                       # Name from /etc/services;
{
        server = /home/user/script.sh          # The service executable
        server_args = ANY_ARGS_HERE        # Any arguments; omit if none
        user = USER                        # Run the service as this user
        socket_type = TYPE                 # stream, dgram, raw, or seqpacket
        wait = nO                      # yes = single-threaded, no = multithreaded
}
```

Then, let's add this service to `/etc/services` :

```
script.sh    3376/tcp
```

Finally restarting xinetd : `service xinetd restart`

**On the client side :**

Now I want to run `script.sh` remotely using `script.sh` service located on the server . it might be something like this : `script.sh  10.0.0.3  3376/tcp`

**Here comes my question :**

what are the configurations to do on the client side in order to execute this script on the server and get results on the client ?

Answer (score 1):

You connect to the port that you've defined in `/etc/services` and `/etc/xinetd`. So either of these commands could work for you, assuming `10.0.0.3` is the remote server hosting the `script.sh` service:

```
nc 10.0.0.3 3376
telnet 10.0.0.3 3376
```

If you're running a firewall on the remote server you will need to punch a hole through it for incoming sessions on 3376/tcp. Without knowing which firewall you're running it's not sensible to offer a solution for that. (If you want to update your Question then I or someone else can offer a fix.)